# How to put data from multiple tables into one model?

Tags: atk4

How to make model, which connects three tables from a database? My DB structure is:

- users

  - id
  - other fields
- users_info

  - id
  - users_id - foreign key to 'users' table
  - other fields
- users_credentials

  - id
  - users_id - foreign key to 'users' table
  - other fields

Former, I wanted to have 2 tables bonded in one model, so I used addRelatedEntity method. Here is my code:

```
class Model_UserInfo extends Model_Table{
    public $entity_code = 'user_info';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('phone')->caption('Nr tel');
        $this->addField('users_id');
    }
    function addRelation(){
        $this->addRelatedEntity('i','users','users_id','left outer');
    }

}
```

and then I extend it in other file -

```
class Model_User extends Model_UserInfo{
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        parent::addRelation();

        $this->newField('name')->caption('Imie')->mandatory(true)->relEntity('i','name');
    }

}
```

And that worked great. But what if I want to bond 3 tables into one model? I cannot extend 2 classes. Is there a way to use addRelatedEntity in Model_User, and have references to Model_UserInfo and Model_Credentials?

Comment: calling parent::addRelation(); is not a good way in terms of object-oriented programming. $this->addRelation(); is better, if function is not defined in current class it's inherited from parent, so it would work exactly same. Just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to probably reverse the joins and start with the "user" table joined by 2 other tables, although it does not matter that much as long as you get the right query.

First, add `$this->debug();` into initialization of your model. That will help you a lot when you will be debugging joins, updates etc.

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
    public $entity_code='users';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->newField('name')
            ->caption('Imie')
            ->mandatory(true);
    }
}

class Model_User_Combined extends Model_User {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addRelatedEntity('info','users_info','inner','related');
        $this->addRelatedEntity('cred','users_credentials','inner','related');

        $this->addField('phone')->caption('Nr tel')->relEntity('info');
        $this->addField('password')->caption('Parol')->relEntity('cred');
    }
}
```

Compared to the solution you have right now, this uses "users" as master table and joins additional tables as "related".

Also you will benefit from inheritance, and `Model_User` will add some basic user fields for you.